# crashing due to onPause or onResume

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to code for my first Android app, but I noticed that my app stopped crashing upon startup with the removal of the onPause/onResume code I had included previously. Any thoughts as to why?

I'm using these heightstring and widthstring variables to calculate perimeter and area with edittext and textview widgets, so after the user inputs, the values are stored into these strings to parsefloat and calculate.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
    editor.putString("heightString", heightString);
    editor.putString("widthString", widthString);
    editor.commit();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    heightString = savedValues.getString("heightString", " ");
    widthString = savedValues.getString("widthString"," ");
}
```

Comment: Is any error reported?

Comment: How are you initializing `savedValues`?

Comment: Can you post what shows in the logcat when the crash happens?

Comment: I actually just hadn't initialized it in the onCreate method. @BenP. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question here: onPause and onResume need to be initialized in the onCreate method. This meant for me simply just appending

```
savedValues = getSharedPreferences("SavedValues", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to the end of the code.

Thanks Ben P. for your comment, which prompted looking into that.